# How do I permanently increase the font size in mrxvt?

Tags: terminal, fonts

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> hotkey increases the font size for the current session in mrxvt. What configuration option will increase the font size permanently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are refering to the font size in the terminal in general, add these lines to your `~/.Xdefaults` file:

```
mrxvt*fontName: DejaVu Sans Mono:pixelsize=13
mrxvt*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono:pixelsize=13
mrxvt*font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:pixelsize=13
```

Replace my font example (DejaVu Sans Mono) with your desired font and size.

Keep in mind that you can use `*` to define the font in all terminals (VT ones like `aterm`, `*rxvt`, `xterm`, etc.) with code like this:

```
*fontName: DejaVu Sans Mono:pixelsize=13
*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono:pixelsize=13
*font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:pixelsize=13
```

Personally I use the second method, but you can define different fonts in different terminals if you like.

Comment: Currently doesn't seem to be working on my box. I'll debug and accept the answer in a few days. Thanks, djura-san.

Comment: @Pedro :: did you tried to see if there are any changes in Xterm with this? There should be some changes or maybe desired font is not available?

Comment: : Thank you for your reply. It does work for Xterm with the second method. mrxvt stays the same. I'll further debug this in another few days.

Comment: This did the trick in ~/.Xresources ::

mrxvt*font: -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--20-200-75-75-c-100-iso8859-15 ::

Thanks user2648, sorry I only got to this 27 months later, I lost the setup that had mrxvt in the meantime.

Comment: mrxvt*font: 10x20 also works.

Answer (score 4):

Since version 0.3.9 mrxvt reads information about resources from ~/.mrxvtrc.
Try putting your favorite font in ~/.mrxvtrc

```
Mrxvt.xft:              1
Mrxvt.xftAntialias:     1
Mrxvt.xftFont:          DejaVu Sans Mono
Mrxvt.xftSize:          13
```

Comment: Note: This works on Ubuntu 18.10